# Can’t Use Parameters for IN Condition in Laravel in DB::select

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

For some strange reason, the parameters are not working for In condition in my query.

If I hard code my parameters the query returns a result:

```php
DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (19009, 19010)
```

These don't return a result:

```php
DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (':vendor_ids')", [
  ':vendor_ids' => implode([
    19010,
    19009,
  ]),
]);

DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (':vendor_ids')", [
  ':vendor_ids' => [
    19010,
    19009,
  ],
]);

DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (':vendor_ids')", [
  ':vendor_ids' => '19009, 19010',
]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding Eloquent and its `whereIn()` functionality?

Comment: Actually, I'm using a pretty complex query that I need to use DB::select. I just simplified it for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IN(:paramters)` will only return one row.

You need to bind parameters separately like `IN(:parameter1, parameter2)`.
So you should get expected result if you do the following

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (':vendor_id1, :vendor_id2',...)", 
    [':vendor_id1' => 1, ':vendor_id2' => 2]);
```

[More details](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#103622)

To dynamically generate parameters, if you have an array of vendor ids iterate through them and create another associative array

```
$vendors = [];
foreach ($vendorId as $id) {
    $vendors[':vendor' . $id] = $id;
}
```

Then

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE vendor_id IN (" . implode(array_keys($vendors), ',') . ")", 
    $vendors);
```

Comment: Ahh yeah this should work but it would be nice if I can make it dynamic. For example, what if in one case I have 10 vendors and in another, i have 5 vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a very nice [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Try this:

```php
$resultCollection = DB::table('my_table')
    ->select('*')
    ->whereIn('vendor_id', [19009, 19010])
    ->get();
```

If you realy want use raw query try [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions)

Like so:

```php
$resultCollection = DB::table('my_table')
    ->whereRaw('vendor_id IN (?)', [19010,19009])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I actually need to use `DB::select` because of the complex query I am running.

Comment: I just simplified the query for here.

Comment: Wel then please provide complete information because we all solved the problem you are describing over here. We can't help if you don't show all information

Comment: There is also a selectRaw method maybe that could be of use